# Swapping elements in a Common Lisp list

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, swap

Is there a Common Lisp function that will swap two elements in a list given their indices and return the modified list?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`rotatef`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_rotate.htm):

```
(rotatef (nth i lst) (nth j lst))
```

Of course, list indexing can be expensive (costing O(*size of list*)), so if you do this with any regularity, you'd rather want to use an array:

```
(rotatef (aref arr i) (aref arr j))
```

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid indexing into the list twice by using `nthcdr` to get the cdr of the cons cell containing the first element that you want to swap and then use `elt` to get the remaining element out of the sublist. This means that you only have to actually index starting from the head of the list once.

```lisp
 (let ((list-tail (nthcdr i list)))
    (rotatef (car list-tail)
             (elt list-tail (- j i)))
    list)
```

At least from my perspective, this is sufficiently tedious to justify a function.

Comment: DAMN! SO needs to do something about the syntax highlighting. I thought it was bad for python.