# Swapping list elements in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I need to swap the elements of a list given two positions (i, j) to implement 2-opt heuristics for the TSP and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950601/swapping-elements-in-a-common-lisp-list?answertab=active#tab-top) recommending the use of `rotatef`.

However, when I try using it I can't understand its behavior.

This is the piece of code that's giving me a headache:

```
(setq loop '(A B C D E F))
> (A B C D E F)

;; Original copy saved in loop
(setq new_tour loop)

(format t "ORIGINAL LOOP: " loop)
> LOOP: (A B C D E F)

(format t "NEW_TOUR: " new_tour)
> NEW_TOUR: (A B C D E F)

(rotatef (nth 0 new_tour) (nth 1 new_tour))
(format t "NEW_TOUR IS NOW: ~a~%" new_tour)
> NEW_TOUR IS NOW: (B A C D E F)

(format t "ORIGINAL LOOP IS NOW: ~a~%" loop)
> ORIGINAL LOOP IS NOW: (B A C D E F)
```

Why does `rotatef` also modify the 'loop' list? Is there a way of swapping the elements of `new_tour` without losing the original list (`loop`)?

Comment: You didn't take a copy. There is only one list in your code.

Comment: you have two variables pointing to the same literal list.

Comment: since your question had nothing to do with AI or heuristics, I have removed these tags...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To copy `loop` use

```
(setq new_tour (copy-list loop))
```