# swap elements between two lists in LISP

Tags: common-lisp, swap

thanks for your support, I am a newbie...
I would like to swap elements BETWEEN two lists in Common-LISP given a certain index of the first and second list, for example:
(1 2 3 4) (A B C D) -> (D 2 3 4) when specified indexes are (0 3).

It might look randomish but it has a nice utility in musical sequences...
Thanks,
Alessandro

Comment: If you want to mutate the lists, [`ROTATEF`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_rotate.htm) should work.

Comment: That's a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950601/swapping-elements-in-a-common-lisp-list#3950697

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swapping elements in a Common Lisp list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950601/swapping-elements-in-a-common-lisp-list)

Answer (score 6):

If you need to use an index, maybe a vector can be more sensible. Use for example [`ROTATEF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_rotate.htm), as explained by jkiiski:

```
CL-USER> (let ((a (vector 1 2 3 4))
               (b (vector 'a 'b 'c 'd)))
           (rotatef (aref a 0) (aref b 3))
           (values a b))
#(D 2 3 4)
#(A B C 1)
```

If you really want to use lists, then use [`NTH`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nth.htm), or [`ELT`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_elt.htm), which works on both kinds of sequences.

Preemptive remark: you cannot modify constant data. Note how vectors `a` and `b` are allocated at runtime. Constant data is data that was computed at read-time or compile-time, and should not be modified at runtime. Quoted lists are constant, as shown by this example:

```
CL-USER> (let ((list '(a b))) (setf (first list) 0) list)
; in: LET ((LIST '(A B)))
;     (SETF (FIRST LIST) 0)
; ==>
;   (SB-KERNEL:%RPLACA LIST 0)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   Destructive function SB-KERNEL:%RPLACA called on constant data: (A B).
;   See also:
;     The ANSI Standard, Special Operator QUOTE
;     The ANSI Standard, Section 3.2.2.3
;
```